# Detect audio finished loading in Javascript with Windows Media Player

Tags: javascript, html, media-player

I have a Windows Media Player embedded in a web page. Some action the user will perform on the page, will trigger the loading of an audio file, from the web server, into the WMP.
I need to be able to detect when the audio has completely finished loading. It could take a significant amount of time over a slow connection.
Best thing would be, if I could get an event, or wait for it some other way, since I need to perform some more actions (Javascript again) once this is done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a readystatechange-event, similar to XMLHttpRequest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910856.aspx

Comment: This page is for Windows Mobile 6.5 but I think it's the same for the regular WMP